# Splitting string into char array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, execvp

I am using user input to pass as an argument to execvp. If I do this as my argument for execvp it works:

```
char *arr[]={ "ls",NULL };
```

When I try to split the user input into the array above it won't let me store the words into the array with this error:
error: 
    cannot convert std::string {aka std::basic_string} to char in assignment

```
int i=0;
cout<<"Enter command with arguments: ";
string line;
getline(cin, line);
istringstream s(line) ;
string word ;
while( s >> word ) 
{
    arr[i]=word;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: you have not initialized the "word" in case of copying try using while (i<word.length )arr[i]=word[i];

Comment: Maybe you can use vector instead of array. Just like this: `vector<string> arr;`.